# Bash shell script to test for inconsistent seg fault

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to create a shell script run a program 100 times or until a segmentation fault is found (the issue is non-consistent)

Here is what I have so far but I don't really understand scripting much and there is a syntax issue.

```
$count = 100;

$seg = 3;

gdb myprog

while [[[![ $seg == 0) ] ] || [ $count == 0 ]]]

do

                $count = $count - 1

                $output = run --myarg

                $seg =  echo $output | grep -F "in malloc_consolidate ()"

done
```

Comment: Use [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check for syntax errors. Based on how many of them there are, I suggest you start out small and try out little pieces to get your scripting feet wet. Play around with variable assignments and looping first. Don't jump straight into the deep end.

Comment: some pointers: `var=` not `$var = `, `count=$((count - 1))`, don't mix `[` and `)`, `echo $output | grep -F "in malloc_consolidate (); seg=$?`

Comment: @SamuelKirschner `echo $output` is broken too, see [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: Keep in mind also that when you run `gdb myprog`, any command after that in your script doesn't run until `gdb` exits -- further script lines **aren't** controlling gdb, they're running *after* gdb.

Comment: ...anyhow, you don't need gdb for this at all; you can detect whether a program was killed with a segfault (or any other specific signal) with `$?`.